# How to make POST Request to Server for OTP Verification?

Tags: post, swift3, verification, one-time-password

I'm having a scenario in which

1)  I'm registering my mobile number using post request.

2)  On successfull registration  will get OTP on my registered mobile number.

3) After receiving the OTP, I have to verify this OTP on the server.

4) And then server will send me the pin on my registered mobile number,using this pin will able to login my app.

Now coming to the issue after on successfull registration I received an OTP but **how to verify this otp and get the pin on my number?.**

I have used below code for this. 0123456789 is my registered mobile number and 3588 is the code have received on successfull registration.

```
 @IBAction func verifyotp(_ sender: Any) {

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "myurl/verifyotp?mobileno=0123456789&otp=3588")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
        }

        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
            self.present(vc, animated: true)

        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

But somehow It didnt match the scenario and m receiving the response like:

```
Optional("{\"Success\":\"No Active account found.\"}")
```

Looking for a help.Thanks in advance.